# how to exclude multiple holidays from DATEDIFF

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, case, datediff, date-difference

Basically, I am trying to create a table in Looker (GBQ SQL dialect) that actively tracks if there is a holiday in between two dates, Then calculates the proper date difference.

This code works... but there is one issue that I can't figure out.
When there are **two or more** holiday days in between the two dates, It still **only subtracts -1 day** (not -2 days.

I want my code to know that **if** there are **multiple holidays**, it should **subtract** the number of **days adjacent** to the **number of holidays**.

The code below is what I use

```
CASE
  WHEN
    ${DATA_1.COUNTRY} = 'GB'
    THEN
    (
      CASE
            WHEN "2022-05-02" BETWEEN ${TIMESTAMPS.created_date} AND ${TIMESTAMPS.first_attempted_date}
            THEN
            DATE_DIFF (${TIMESTAMPS.first_attempted_date},${TIMESTAMPS.created_date}, DAY) -
            DATE_DIFF (${TIMESTAMPS.first_attempted_date},${TIMESTAMPS.created_date}, WEEK(SUNDAY)) - 1

            WHEN"2022-05-03" BETWEEN ${TIMESTAMPS.created_date} AND ${TIMESTAMPS.first_attempted_date}
            THEN
            DATE_DIFF (${TIMESTAMPS.first_attempted_date},${TIMESTAMPS.created_date}, DAY) -
            DATE_DIFF (${TIMESTAMPS.first_attempted_date},${TIMESTAMPS.created_date}, WEEK(SUNDAY)) - 1

            WHEN"2022-05-04" BETWEEN ${TIMESTAMPS.created_date} AND ${TIMESTAMPS.first_attempted_date}
            THEN
            DATE_DIFF (${TIMESTAMPS.first_attempted_date},${TIMESTAMPS.created_date}, DAY) -
            DATE_DIFF (${TIMESTAMPS.first_attempted_date},${TIMESTAMPS.created_date}, WEEK(SUNDAY)) - 1

          ELSE
          DATE_DIFF (${TIMESTAMPS.first_attempted_date},${TIMESTAMPS.created_date}, DAY) -
          DATE_DIFF (${TIMESTAMPS.first_attempted_date},${TIMESTAMPS.created_date}, WEEK(SUNDAY))

      END
      )
  ELSE
    DATE_DIFF (${TIMESTAMPS.first_attempted_date},${TIMESTAMPS.created_date}, DAY) -
    DATE_DIFF (${TIMESTAMPS.first_attempted_date},${TIMESTAMPS.created_date}, WEEK(SUNDAY))
END;;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your `CASE` statement is functioning as expected, they are resolved until a condition is met as true then exit.  Meaning that based on your code it would either resolve to have a `-1` or exit to the `ELSE`.

What you would typically do is have some kind of date dimension that includes an is_holiday type flag, or a holiday table that specifically lists holidays.  I've stubbed out some sample data to show you how this can be achieved:

```
with holidays as (
  select 'GB' as country, DATE '2022-05-02' as holiday_date union all
  select 'GB' as country, DATE '2022-05-03' as holiday_date union all
  select 'GB' as country, DATE '2022-05-04' as holiday_date union all
  select 'GB' as country, DATE '2022-06-02' as holiday_date union all
  select 'GB' as country, DATE '2022-06-03' as holiday_date union all
  select 'GB' as country, DATE '2022-08-29' as holiday_date
),
sample_data as (
  select 'GB' as country, DATE '2022-05-25' as first_attempted_date, DATE '2022-05-01' as created_date union all
  select 'GB' as country, DATE '2022-01-30' as first_attempted_date, DATE '2022-01-01' as created_date union all
  select 'GB' as country, DATE '2022-09-01' as first_attempted_date, DATE '2022-01-01' as created_date --union all

)

select sd.country,
  sd.created_date,
  sd.first_attempted_date,
  DATE_DIFF (sd.first_attempted_date,sd.created_date, DAY) as diff,
  count(h.holiday_date) as count_holidays,
  DATE_DIFF (sd.first_attempted_date,sd.created_date, DAY)-count(h.holiday_date) as diff_holiday
from sample_data sd
left join holidays h
 on sd.country = h.country
  and h.holiday_date between sd.created_date and sd.first_attempted_date
group by sd.country,
  sd.created_date,
  sd.first_attempted_date
```

With the code above you are essentially looking for dates that fall within a range for the given country then counting the return.  Once the return is in you can subtract it from your date_diff.
This results in the following output:

[image]

I am unsure as to why you are including a `DATE_DIFF` based on `WEEK` in your original calculation, but if you can provide your use case there I may be able to help.  With that logic it is currently saying:

(# of days between two dates) - (# of weeks between two dates)

This makes sense if you are trying to eliminate one of the weekend dates as well, just wasn't clear on your question if that was your intent.